# Simulate account-to-account payout using PayPal API

Tags: c#, .net, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm new to PayPal .NET API.
All that I want at first is just to make a simple virtual money transfer between two sandbox accounts.

I have registered two accounts with e-mails some1@fake.com and some2@fake.com with 1000$ balance.
After the following code executes

```
        var apiContext = new APIContext
        {
            AccessToken = "Bearer [MyToken]",
            Config = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "mode", "sandbox" } }
        };

        var payout = new Payout
        {
            sender_batch_header = new PayoutSenderBatchHeader
            {
                sender_batch_id = "batch_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 8),
                email_subject = "You have payment"
            },

            items = new List<PayoutItem>
            {
                new PayoutItem
                {
                    recipient_type = PayoutRecipientType.EMAIL,
                    amount = new Currency { value="1.5", currency="USD" },
                    receiver = "some2@fake.com",
                    note="Thank you",
                    sender_item_id = "item_1"
                }
            }
        };

        var created = payout.Create(apiContext, false);
```

I see one more transaction of type /v1/payments/payouts in my PayPal sandbox dashboard, but the payout batch is always in PENDING state. No money transferred.

What is the right way to accomplish such a basic operation?

Comment: Have you check if both receiver are exist in PayPal Sandbox? Basically the pending is due to the account is not exist and need to be created so the payment could be claim.

Comment: Well, the problem indeed was in my account. My application was bound to the default account, which -facilitator email has no money. So every asynchronous payout call first sets to PENDING and finally ends up with transaction FAILED. I created another Business account, bound it to a new application, and all started work propely.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem was in my account. My application was bound to the default account, which '-facilitator' email has no money. So every asynchronous payout call first sets to PENDING and finally ends up with transaction FAILED. I created another Business account, bound it to a new application, and all started work propely.